# parasoft SOA Test - How to call Java code in parasoft

Tags: java, soa, parasoft

I am trying to run a java program as an executable from my Parasoft Test suite. The executable just executes once the test is run and store results in one folder..
  But Now, as part of enhancement , I need to pass a argument to Java code and java code needs that argument to generate results in specific folders. Is anyone aware how java code needs to be integrated with SOA Test and how an argument can be passed from SOA test and how that argument should be dealt in java code?

Would appreciate any help on this.. Thanks

Comment: Can you post any code showing what you have tried?

Comment: My java code runs absolutely fine when I run it outside or I give as an executable from SOA TEST, But now as part of enhancement, I need to get an input from parasoft and I need to use that input in my java code.I need help in that area.. thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I understand this wrong.

You want to start a Java application from inside SOATest. This will run independently and you could also start it from the command line?
In that case you could use Groovy to spawn of the process as you would on the command line. Check out the [Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management).

```
*** SOATest.ExtensionTool ***

import com.parasoft.api.Application;
import com.parasoft.api.ScriptingContext;

def callJavaFromSoaTest(Object input, ScriptingContext scriptingContext) {
  command = 'java -jar /path/to/your/java/class/JavaMain.jar Parameter';
  result = command.execute().text;
  Application.showMessage(result);
}

*** Java Class ***

public class JavaMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "Harry";
    if (args.length > 0) {
      name = args[0];
    }
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ", how is your day?");
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement com.parasoft.api in you java code in order get the argument you need;  More detail can be found in the help section search for: "Extensibility (Scripting) Basics"

Define a test suite variable, store your value in it, then call:

varValue = context.getValue("x")

Here is a Java example that gets a value from a datasource.

```
package examples;

import soaptest.api.*;
import com.parasoft.api.*;

public class Keyword {

    public Object getKeywords(Object input, ExtensionToolContext context) 
            throws com.parasoft.data.DataSourceException {
        String[] titles = new String[1];
        titles[0] = context.getValue("Books", "keywords");
        return SOAPUtil.getXMLFromString(titles);
    }

}
```

Comment: I already have a standalone java code which is with multiple classes and MAIN () . If I implement this, Should I make changes to current java code?